# Twitter digits Embeddable Widget (JS) not able to get mobile number after signup

Tags: javascript, php, twitter, twitter-digits

**Basically I am using embeddable widget of twitter digits for sign up after sign up I want the mobile no of this user, I dint got any reference on web, nor official documentation**

**What I have done so far is**

***this is my index file***

```
 document.getElementById('digits-sdk').onload = function() {
 Digits.init({ consumerKey: 'my key' });


 Digits.embed({
 container: '.my-digits-container',
 theme: {
 accent: '315B7F',       
 background: '002747',   
 label: 'FFF',          
 border: '324F67'       
 },
 phoneNumber: '+91'
 })


 .done(onLogin) 
 .fail(onLoginFailure);


 function onLogin(loginResponse){
 var oAuthHeaders = loginResponse.oauth_echo_headers;
 alert("yo "+oAuthHeaders['X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization']);
 var verifyData = {
 authHeader: oAuthHeaders['X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization'],
 apiUrl: oAuthHeaders['X-Auth-Service-Provider']
 };


 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: digits.php,
  data: verifyData,
  success: function(data)
  {
    alert("do "+data);
  }
});
```

***this is my digits.php file which have curl call***

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "'.$_POST["apiUrl"].'" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "'.$_POST["authHeader"].'"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,   array('Content-Type:     text/plain')); 

$result=curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result;



?>
```

I get following error when I call digits.php file in AJAX req from index page.

**caught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "mydomain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.**